# Asymmetrik FHIR mongo: partial patient stored

Tags: hl7-fhir, node-fhir-server-core

I'm running `node-fhir-server-mongo`.

I'm trying to create a patient:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:3000/4_0_0/Patient/example1" -H "application/fhir+json" --data "@patient.json"
```

My `patient.json` is:

```json
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "example",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n\t\t\t<table>\n\t\t\t\t<tbody>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Name</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Peter James \n              <b>Chalmers</b> (&quot;Jim&quot;)\n            </td>\n\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Address</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>534 Erewhon, Pleasantville, Vic, 3999</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Contacts</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Home: unknown. Work: (03) 5555 6473</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>Id</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>MRN: 12345 (Acme Healthcare)</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t\t\t</tbody>\n\t\t\t</table>\n\t\t</div>"
  },
  "identifier": [
    {
      "use": "usual",
      "type": {
        "coding": [
          {
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
            "code": "MR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "system": "urn:oid:1.2.36.146.595.217.0.1",
      "value": "12345",
      "period": {
        "start": "2001-05-06"
      },
      "assigner": {
        "display": "Acme Healthcare"
      }
    }
  ],
  "active": true,
  "name": [
    {
      "use": "official",
      "family": "Chalmers",
      "given": [
        "Peter",
        "James"
      ]
    },
    {
      "use": "usual",
      "given": [
        "Jim"
      ]
    },
    {
      "use": "maiden",
      "family": "Windsor",
      "given": [
        "Peter",
        "James"
      ],
      "period": {
        "end": "2002"
      }
    }
  ],
  "telecom": [
    {
      "use": "home"
    },
    {
      "system": "phone",
      "value": "(03) 5555 6473",
      "use": "work",
      "rank": 1
    },
    {
      "system": "phone",
      "value": "(03) 3410 5613",
      "use": "mobile",
      "rank": 2
    },
    {
      "system": "phone",
      "value": "(03) 5555 8834",
      "use": "old",
      "period": {
        "end": "2014"
      }
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1974-12-25",
  "_birthDate": {
    "extension": [
      {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-birthTime",
        "valueDateTime": "1974-12-25T14:35:45-05:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "deceasedBoolean": false,
  "address": [
    {
      "use": "home",
      "type": "both",
      "text": "534 Erewhon St PeasantVille, Rainbow, Vic  3999",
      "line": [
        "534 Erewhon St"
      ],
      "city": "PleasantVille",
      "district": "Rainbow",
      "state": "Vic",
      "postalCode": "3999",
      "period": {
        "start": "1974-12-25"
      }
    }
  ],
  "contact": [
    {
      "relationship": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0131",
              "code": "N"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "name": {
        "family": "du Marché",
        "_family": {
          "extension": [
            {
              "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-own-prefix",
              "valueString": "VV"
            }
          ]
        },
        "given": [
          "Bénédicte"
        ]
      },
      "telecom": [
        {
          "system": "phone",
          "value": "+33 (237) 998327"
        }
      ],
      "address": {
        "use": "home",
        "type": "both",
        "line": [
          "534 Erewhon St"
        ],
        "city": "PleasantVille",
        "district": "Rainbow",
        "state": "Vic",
        "postalCode": "3999",
        "period": {
          "start": "1974-12-25"
        }
      },
      "gender": "female",
      "period": {
        "start": "2012"
      }
    }
  ],
  "managingOrganization": {
    "reference": "Organization/1"
  }
}
```

However, when I'm trying to look at mongo collections, I'm only getting:

```
> db.Patient_4_0_0.find();
{ "_id" : "example", "id" : "example", "meta" : { "versionId" : "1", "lastUpdated" : "2021-04-22T12:35:57+00:00" }, "resourceType" : "Patient" }
```

Any other data is stored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The id in the resource should match the id on the url for the PUT. The server will give an error when you do not follow that rule.

So either change your Patient.id to 'example1' or your url to 'http://localhost:3000/4_0_0/Patient/example'.
Then check the response for the status code, and the resource that is reflected back to you, so you can see whether the server has processed the request as expected. You can also do a GET on your patient, to see what the server has stored, instead of looking in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this header to your command

```
"Content-Type: application/fhir+json"
```

Seems you have not specified the header name in your command.

Comment: Also the id value should match the one in endpoint, i.e, example1 in your case

Answer (score 0):

1. Change verb to POST
2. Set content type value to  `"Content-Type: application/fhir+json"`
3. Set url to `http://localhost:3000/4_0_0/Patient`